# Magento2 : Show summery total on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, totals

How to display summery total on checkout page on sidebar above cart items list? 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to display the tax summary? or order summary over here?

Comment: order summary, same as on cart page

Comment: It's not showing on shipping step

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two changes required to display summary in shipping step.
Override both files in your current theme.

**1.** change `/Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js` file

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals, stepNavigator) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            },
            getTotals: function() {
                return totals.totals();
            },
            isFullMode: function() {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }
                //return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping'); // comment this line to enable right side bar in checkout shipping step.  
                return true; //add this line to display forcefully summary in shipping step.
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now order summary will be displayed in shipping step.

2. change `/Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping.js` file
   This change is for **to update shipping charge in the selection of shipping methods.**

Change **`getValue()`** function.

```
 getValue: function () {
            var price;

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            //var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount; //comment this line

           var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod(); //add these both line
              var price =  shippingMethod.amount; // update data on change of the shipping method

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: @ketankp-borada Please try this solution and let me know it's working for you or not.?

Comment: not working,only cart items are shown http://prntscr.com/j6r8sk

Comment: After file change, Have you upgrade data ? and clean cache ?
please check in private browser because code is uploaded after testing.

Comment: Yes working now,but totals are not updating after changing shipping method only shipping title updating.

Comment: I will update my answer and let you know.

Comment: Perfect Solution .. !!! Thanks  @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.

Comment: thank you but it only work for shipping step.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I'm creating these files in my custom theme but it can also be done with an extension. If you use an extension then the requirejs-config.js file will need to be adjust slightly according to the magento documentation.

theme/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin.js:

```
define([

], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            isFullMode: function () {
                var result = this._super();
                
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }
                
                return true;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-mixin.js:

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information'
], function (
    quote,
    setShippingInformationAction
) {
    'use strict';
    
    return function (Component) {
        var currentMethod;

        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this._super();
                
                quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function (method) {
                    setShippingInformationAction();
                });
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**UPDATE Magento 2.4.3**
When I updated to magento 2.4.3 from 2.3.6 I started getting an error that the billing address street was not type of array. This is due to new behavior in the checkout where the billing address is rendered as soon as the shipping data is pushed to the server. Since we are pushing it early (potentially before the shipping address has been entered) this fix is needed.

theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-billing-address.js:

line 27 replace:

```
quote.billingAddress(address);
```

with:

```
if(Array.isArray(billingAddress.street)){
    quote.billingAddress(address);
}
```