# How to show checkout price summary in shipping step Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, order-summary

The checkout sidebar cart summary with the price is displayed on at payment step, I want to show them on the shipping step as well. is there any solution to do this?

Screenshots

Here I want to show:
[image]

This section:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below step need to follow:

Step 1: create require config js files under the

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
            'Vendor_Modulename/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin': true
        },
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
            'Vendor_Modulename/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
        },
    }
}};
```

Step 2: Create an abstract total js for showing order summary in step 1 as below

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
],
function (stepNavigator, quote, totalsDefaultProvider) {
    "use strict";

    var estimateTotalsShipping = function () {
        totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
    };

    // this should be added to get correct totals
    quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(estimateTotalsShipping);

    return function (abstractTotal) {
        return abstractTotal.extend({
            isFullMode: function() {
                if (!this.getTotals() || stepNavigator.getActiveItemIndex() === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true; //add this line to display forcefully summary in shipping step.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Step 3: Create a file for showing shipping method in order summary total.

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, Component, quote) {
    'use strict';
    return function (shipping) {
        return shipping.extend({
            getValue: function () {
                var price;

                if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                    return this.notCalculatedMessage;
                }
                //var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount; //comment this line

                var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod(); //add these both line
                var price =  shippingMethod.amount; // update data on change of the shipping method

                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            }
        });
    }});
```

Comment: i have already done this. i did not used mixin because i am working in custom theme.

Comment: Mixin is used for needed parts to change that function

Comment: If you helpfull then approved answer.

Comment: Using this solution, the shipping charge is not added to the order total. The order total is displaying wrong value.

Comment: I added these js files in custom theme. Order summary is displayed on shipping step. However, its not displayed on payment step.

Comment: For payment step remove `|| stepNavigator.getActiveItemIndex() === 1` part

Comment: How would you update the order total amount? Because now it's wrong after the shipping price is added to summary. @MGento Did you figure this out?

Comment: I found how to update totals here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255767/how-to-display-order-summary-sidebar-in-shipping-step-of-checkout-page-in-magent/255775#255775

Comment: This appears to work pretty OK though I had to alter the code a bit. In requirejs I used  `'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping'` instead of `'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping'` and change the method name from `getValue` to `getIncludingValue`. I'm using Magento 2.3.5